# Php-script executes in case of adding definitely 3 images, I need to make it insert data into DB even if there is only one file

Tags: php, mysqli, file-upload

Firstly, I had only one picture to submit, so that there was nothing sophisticated to accomplish, but now there could be either one, two or three images. I made my code too complicated.

The main problem is:

```
<div id="upload-area">
     <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
          <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Add Photo or Video
     </label>
    <input name="files[]" id="file-upload" accept="image/*" type="file" multiple/>
```

I have a submit form on the website, there is an upload area to choose multiple files, so I have an array of them.

The first my idea was to run a “for” loop through all indices, but I failed, because realized that it could have worked only if I need to send images to the DB one by one(as a sequence of records) neither as a one unite raw in the table.

That’s why I added duplicated parts of code, but with different url, image name, path and etc number.

But I understood it works properly only for 3 images chosen.

I approached to make something like this:

```
if ($_FILES["files"]["name"][1] === null | $_FILES["files"]["name"][1].length === 0) {
$image1 = “ “;
$url1 = “ “;
else {
  $upload_path1 = "uploads/1" . $_FILES["files"]["name"][1];
  $url1 = "https://bettercity.online/$upload_path1";
  $image1 = $_FILES["files"]["name"][1];
  $uploadedfile1 = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][1];
  $image_type1 = $_FILES["files"]["type"][1];
}
```

But there is a problem with inserting those empty variables values that I am unable to solve.

The current(abysmal) code:

```
$upload_path0 = "uploads/0" . $_FILES["files"]["name"][0];
$url0 = "https://bettercity.online/$upload_path0";
$image0 = $_FILES["files"]["name"][0];
$uploadedfile0 = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];
$image_type = $_FILES["files"]["type"][0]; 
$upload_path1 = "uploads/1" . $_FILES["files"]["name"][1];
$url1 = "https://bettercity.online/$upload_path1";
$image1 = $_FILES["files"]["name"][1];
$uploadedfile1 = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][1];
$image_type1 = $_FILES["files"]["type"][1];
$upload_path2 = "uploads/2" . $_FILES["files"]["name"][2];
$url2 = "https://bettercity.online/$upload_path2";
$image2 = $_FILES["files"]["name"][2];
$uploadedfile2 = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][2];
$image_type2 = $_FILES["files"]["type"][2];
$ftp_server = " ";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
$user = " "; 
$pass = " "; 
    if (ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $pass)) 
    { 
        if ($_FILES["files"]["error"][0] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["files"]["error"][0] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {  
                 if($image_type=='image/png' || $image_type=='image/x-png')
                    {
                      if($image_type1=='image/png' || $image_type1=='image/x-png')
                       {
                         if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                          elseif($image_type2=='image/jpeg' || $image_type2=='image/jpg' || $image_type2 == 'image/pjpeg')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                       }
                      elseif($image_type1=='image/jpeg' || $image_type1=='image/jpg' || $image_type1 == 'image/pjpeg')
                       {
                         if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                          elseif($image_type2=='image/jpeg' || $image_type2=='image/jpg' || $image_type2 == 'image/pjpeg')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 elseif($image_type=='image/jpeg' || $image_type=='image/jpg' || $image_type == 'image/pjpeg')
                    {
                      if($image_type1=='image/png' || $image_type1=='image/x-png')
                       {
                         if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                          elseif($image_type2=='image/jpeg' || $image_type2=='image/jpg' || $image_type2 == 'image/pjpeg')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                       }
                      elseif($image_type1=='image/jpeg' || $image_type1=='image/jpg' || $image_type1 == 'image/pjpeg')
                       {
                         if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                          elseif($image_type2=='image/jpeg' || $image_type2=='image/jpg' || $image_type2 == 'image/pjpeg')
                          {
                            $src0 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile0);
                            $src1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile1);
                            $src2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile2);
                          }
                       }
                    }

                 $new_width=768;
                 $new_height=500;
                 $image_p=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
                 imagealphablending($image_p, false);
                 imagesavealpha($image_p, true);
                 list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile0);

                 $image_p1=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
                 imagealphablending($image_p1, false);
                 imagesavealpha($image_p1, true);
                 list($width1,$height1)=getimagesize($uploadedfile1);
                 $image_p2=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
                 imagealphablending($image_p2, false);
                 imagesavealpha($image_p2, true);
                 list($width2,$height2)=getimagesize($uploadedfile2);
                 imagecopyresampled($image_p,$src0,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width,$height);
                 imagecopyresampled($image_p1,$src1,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width1,$height1);
                 imagecopyresampled($image_p2,$src2,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width2,$height2);
                 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0], $upload_path0) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][1], $upload_path1) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][2], $upload_path2))
                 {
                    if ($resp['status'] == 'OK') {
                   $latitude = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                   $longitude = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO problem_data(username, name, description, mediafile, mediafile1, mediafile2, district_id, category_id, location, latitude, longitude, rating, counter, general_rating, status_id, upl_date) values('$username','$name','$description','$url0','$url1','$url2','$district_id','$category_id','$location','$latitude','$longitude', 0.0, 0, 0.0, 1, '$date')";

                    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
                        {
                        if($image_type=='image/png' || $image_type=='image/x-png'){
                          if($image_type1=='image/png' || $image_type1=='image/x-png'){
                            if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png'){
                             imagepng($image_p,$upload_path0,9) ; 
                             imagepng($image_p1,$upload_path1,9) ; 
                             imagepng($image_p2,$upload_path2,9) ; 
                            }
                             else {
                             imagepng($image_p,$upload_path0,9) ; 
                             imagepng($image_p1,$upload_path1,9) ; 
                             imagejpeg($image_p2,$upload_path2,100); 
                            }
                          }
                          else {
                             if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png'){
                             imagepng($image_p,$upload_path0,9) ; 
                             imagejpeg($image_p1,$upload_path1,100);
                             imagepng($image_p2,$upload_path2,9) ; 
                             }
                             else {
                             imagepng($image_p,$upload_path0,9) ; 
                             imagejpeg($image_p1,$upload_path1,100);
                             imagejpeg($image_p2,$upload_path2,100); 
                             }
                          }
                        }
                        else {
                          if($image_type1=='image/png' || $image_type1=='image/x-png'){
                            if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png'){
                             imagejpeg($image_p0,$upload_path0,100);
                             imagepng($image_p1,$upload_path1,9) ; 
                             imagepng($image_p2,$upload_path2,9) ; 
                            }
                             else {
                             imagejpeg($image_p0,$upload_path0,100);
                             imagepng($image_p1,$upload_path1,9) ; 
                             imagejpeg($image_p2,$upload_path2,100); 
                            }
                          }
                          else {
                             if($image_type2=='image/png' || $image_type2=='image/x-png'){
                             imagejpeg($image_p0,$upload_path0,100);
                             imagejpeg($image_p1,$upload_path1,100);
                             imagepng($image_p2,$upload_path2,9) ; 
                             }
                             else {
                             imagejpeg($image_p0,$upload_path0,100);
                             imagejpeg($image_p1,$upload_path1,100);
                             imagejpeg($image_p2,$upload_path2,100); 
                             }
                          }
                          }
                        }

                  echo 'Problem uploaded';
                  imagedestroy($image_p);
                  imagedestroy($image_p1);
                  imagedestroy($image_p2);
                    }
                 }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't post your code as external links. Snip out the relevant parts and include them in your question. It's important to keep things self-contained.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I see. Well, I’m grateful indeed. You literally broadened my horizons with regard to the programming style, because I have been always convinced by mentors that PHP is originally procedural language and I should use it strictly like that, ignoring the fact that it completely supports OOP paradigms. Subsequently, according to your piece of advice I assume that I should entirely decline using the procedural style not only in this script, but in general as well, and refactor whole code into OOP-like. Thanks!

Comment: Your mentors are living in the 1990s when PHP 4 was the totality of PHP. With PHP 5 you have considerably more tools at your disposal and it's ignorant to shun them just because of tradition. Another thing to consider is using a development framework like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) for something minimal or [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) for a full-featured solution. There's other options available on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) worth exploring.

Comment: The reason frameworks are important is because in the 1990s there weren't a lot of threats compared to today and many attack vectors had yet to be discovered. Now there's [hundreds of things](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) you need to keep in mind when writing production quality code. A framework is typically secure by default and if you follow their guidelines, it will stay secure. Core PHP makes zero claims about security. In this code here there's a risk someone could inject a hostile path like `../../../../index.php` and overwrite parts of your site.

Comment: Amazing, you are my PHP-God 